# Append based on another reference

Tags: python, numpy

Im allowed to use Numpy for the task.

I need to show the total sales in a month with two lists: dates and sales.

My approach is to make a list of all sales during a month by stripping the month off the date, creating a 2D matrix and adding the values that check for each month.

```
import numpy as np

dates = ["02/01/19", "03/02/19"]
sales = ["10.50", "12.20"]
month = [x.strip("0").split("/")[0] for x in dates]
monthsales = np.vstack((month, sales)).astype(np.float)

def monthlysales():
    jan = []
    for i in monthsales[0, 0:]:
        if i == 1:
            jan.append()
    s = input("Pick month: ")
    if s == "1":
        print("Sales total for Jan is:", np.sum(jan), "USD")
    else:
        print("Not a valid month")
    return
print(monthsales)
print(monthlysales())
```

The problem is that I dont know what to append so that it takes the second row of my matrix, which would complete the code

Comment: Please clarify the last sentence - what do you want this extra logic to do, exactly?

Comment: but *why* would you use numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution *keeping your logic*:

Here I loop over the months (as you did, but here using `enumerate`), and look for when the month is equal to 1. Using `enumerate` allows us to know the column number of when the month equals 1 (`id`). Then it's just a matter of appending the sales (row 1) at the month we're interested in (`id`)

```
import numpy as np

dates = ["02/01/19", "03/02/19"]
sales = ["10.50", "12.20"]
month = [x.strip("0").split("/")[0] for x in dates]
monthsales = np.vstack((month, sales)).astype(np.float)

def monthlysales():
    jan = []
    # Loop over months with enumerate
    for id, month in enumerate(monthsales[0]):
        if month == 1:
            # Append sales (row 1) at column id
            jan.append(monthsales[1, id])
    s = input("Pick month: ")
    if s == "1":
        print("Sales total for Jan is:", np.sum(jan), "USD")
    else:
        print("Not a valid month")

print(monthsales)
print(monthlysales())
```

Of course, since you're allowed to use numpy you could have avoided any looping altogether. Consider the following line:

```
monthsales[1, monthsales[0] == 1].sum()
```

This sums up the sales for all the January months in one line. No loops. For any reasonable amount of data this will be considerably quicker than the solution with `enumerate`.

Looking more like your initial solution you could have had:

```
def monthlysales():
    s = int(input("Pick month: "))
    if s >= 1 and s <= 12:
        monies = monthsales[1, monthsales[0] == s].sum()
        print("Sales total for month {} is {} USD".format(s, monies))
    else:
        print("Not a valid month")
```

Comment: Thanks! The second answer was perfect. Sorry for the late reply I just got back home.

Comment: No bother. I'm glad this was useful for you :)